# Get a specific content (with Ajax) of a CKEditor among many other CKEditor which have all the same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I work with a PHP foreach loop that generates many datas from the server. In the same time, it also generates multiple CKEditor elements matching specific datas.

To have multiple CKEditor elements, I used :

```js
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
        CKEDITOR.replaceClass = 'ta-contribution'; //Here ta-contribution is a class
    });
</script>
```

Instead of

```js
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('ta-contribution'); //Here ta-contribution is an id
</script>
```

Here is my php file (with a foreach loop), assuming I put off all my php variable :

```html
<?php
        
        foreach ($this->data as data) {
        
        ?>

    <!-- blah-blah -->

<div id="contributions">
<textarea class="ta-contribution" id="ta-contribution"   name="text" class="col-md-10" style="height:300%; padding: 0px;"  required autofocus></textarea>
<input class="btn-contribution btn btn-primary col-md-2"  type="submit"/>
<input id="num_user" type="hidden" name="num_user" value="<?=$this->numuser?>">
</div>

   <!-- blah-blah -->
          <?php
             }?>

   <!-- blah-blah -->
```

I want to retrieve the current CKEditor content of the button where I click for Ajax purpose.

I know we can use this to retrieve CKEditor content:

```js
ckEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.ta-contribution.getData();
```

But it only works when we have one instance of CKeditor with an id, I have multiple instance with a same class.

Here is the beginning of my ajax.js file where I want to retrieve the contents :

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-contribution').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        //I am stuck
       


    })


})
```

But I'm blocked because I can't get CKEditor contents.
How can I do that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that your for loop is causing many fields to all have the same `id` (contributions, ta-contribution, and num_user). I'd add a counter to your loop and then append that counter to all those ids (and probably the `name` attributes too). Once you did that, you would be able to access them by id using the `instances` property as you mentioned.

You can still keep the `ta-contribution` class and instantiate all the editors using that class while still allowing you to access each instance by id.

```
CKEDITOR.replaceClass('ta-contribution');
CKEDITOR.instances.ta-contribution1.getData();
CKEDITOR.instances.ta-contribution2.getData();
CKEDITOR.instances.ta-contribution3.getData();
```